# Counts of multiple variables in multiple columns R

Tags: r, dataframe, count

This is a sample of my data frame. Each number (1-27) represents a different reason for supporting a program.

```
> df[10:15]
reason1  reason2  reason3  reason4  reason5  reason6
   1        2        6        13       14       27
   2        4        5        13       27       NA
   5       10       12        18       26       11
   8       27       NA        NA       NA       NA
```

I would like to get the total counts of each number (1-27) in the six columns (reason1-reason6).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm understanding the question to be a request for a tabulation of the "reasons" values:

```
 table( unlist( df[10:15] ) )
```

If you need the count of NA's which seems unlikely then look at the optional parameters in `?table`

Answer (score 0):

Or if you wanted a data frame you can use dplyr, which will include NAs:

```
library(dplyr)
df[10:15] %>% gather() %>% group_by(key, value) %>% summarise(N=n()) %>% arrange(key, value)
```

Your result is:

```
# A tibble: 22 x 3
# Groups:   key [6]
   key     value     N
   <chr>   <chr> <int>
 1 reason1 1         1
 2 reason1 2         1
 3 reason1 5         1
 4 reason1 8         1
 5 reason2 10        1
 6 reason2 2         1
 7 reason2 27        1
 8 reason2 4         1
 9 reason3 12        1
10 reason3 5         1
# ... with 12 more rows
```